# Piano Fingering 3 octaves

Tags: piano, fingering

I'm learning a new song and in one part the left hand has to span and I am not sure how to finger them. Can anyone help?

Ascending:

C   G   C   D  Eb  G  C  D  Eb   G   C   D  Eb

Descending:Same thing but backwards

D   C   G   Eb   D    C    G    Eb    D   C   G

I wish I had a piano teacher to help :'(.

Thank you guys/gals :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sequence reminds me of Chopin's *Revolutionary Etude op. 10 No. 12*.

Thus

Ascending:

`C G C D Eb G C D Eb G C D Eb`

`5 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 3 2`

Descending:

`D C G Eb D C G Eb D C G`

`3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2`

This may not be the only one answer so you can find lots of instruction on fingering of this piece.